# Android multiple APKs using same codebase causing inconvenience to users

Tags: android, apk

I have a library project containing the codebase for my application. I have a demo and a full release, which include this library containing all of the Activities, etc. Most players start out with the demo, and if they like it, they grab the full version. However, they often don't immediately uninstall the demo, and proceed to have them both on their device at the same time. This seems to cause a popup, asking which application (demo or full) to open each Activity with as the player movies through the Activities.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, or is it an unavoidable side-effect of having both APKs on the device concurrently?

Comment: I think it is unavoidable if they are both installed. You could make both apk's check for the existence of the other, and if both are present prompt them to uninstall the demo version. If you launch the correct intent you can take them straight to the unstall [your demo app] page so they just have to hit the button, no digging through settings or anything;

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I was thinking. I'll create the demo uninstall popup as you suggested. Thanks for your help; if you post your answer, I'll mark this one solved.

Comment: What kind of Intent pattern do you use for opening activity? Can you post some code snippet (how activity is opened) with AndroidManifest.xml (how activity is defined)?

Comment: All I've done is pretty much copied the Activity nodes from the AndroidManifest of the library broject into each of the child projects. I then changed the paths to absolute package paths in the XML. Everything works just fine, it's just the annoying popups.

Comment: I've decided that this is pretty much unavoidable when both APKs are installed, and instead I'm just going to warn the users, and give them the option of uninstalling the demo, or continue to stumble through the application. I'll post the code in another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I "resolve" the issue by detecting the presence of both games, and then prompting to uninstall the demo version, should anyone be interested in the future:

```
public class UpdateManager {

    public static void checkForBothVersions(final Activity activity) {

        PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();

        //# We want to intentionally cause an Exception. This will let us know
        //# whether there is only one version installed.
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo("package.full", 0);
            packageManager.getPackageInfo("package.demo", 0);

            //# If we get here, then both are installed. Let's display our warning.
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Warning!");
            builder.setMessage("" +
                    "We've detected that you have both the FULL and DEMO versions of Application installed.\n" +
                    "This can cause undesired results. We suggest uninstalling the DEMO version of Application." +
                    "")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Uninstall DEMO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:package.demo");
                    //# Start the delete intent for the demo
                    activity.startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri) );
                    //# We don't wanna call finish here. We want the delete Intent to open
                    //# and once the user closes that Intent, it should go back to the
                    //# calling RB Activity and call onResume where the check cycle will
                    //# restart.
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent("package.lib.SplashActivity"));
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }catch( Exception e ) {
            Log.i("UpdateManager", "Only one version of Application installed.");
            activity.startActivity(new Intent("package.lib.SplashActivity"));
            activity.finish();
        }       
    }   
}
```

I just call this method from the onResume method of both the demo and full applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a different package between your demo and full versions. Even though your manifest has a different package defined (required since you can't have two apps on Google Play with the same package), the activities you're calling through too I'm assuming exist on your library project, which would be using the library package for both versions of your app.

To work around this, you should declare every activity in the manifest that is in your library in your child projects as well.

Comment: I'm not having conflicting package issues -- each application has their own package defined.

Comment: Are you redefining the package for shared activities in the library? or are you using the library package.

Comment: Just putting the absolute package path in the AndroidManifest.xml to the Activities in the library package.